# Multiple blank anchor tags being generated in while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I have the following loop:

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card__content">
                <h3 class="title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 50, '...');?></h3>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 30, '...' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endwhile; 
?>
```

And it's rendered markup looks like this:

```
<div class="card ">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card__content ">
            <h3 class="title">title</h3>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<a href=#"></a>
```

Why is this happening? What I'm expecting is a single anchor that wraps `.card`

Comment: In your code, the anchor tag is wrapped around the `<div class="card">`, but in the output, it is inside that tag.  Not sure how!

Comment: @NigelRen - Yeah, that's whats confusing me

Comment: Simple check would be to change something in your code (change it to h2) and see if the changes are reflected in the output.

Comment: I tried your same code, I did not get this issue. It's working fine for me.

Comment: No issue in code you mention in question. Maybe somethings else. check  page template code.

Comment: The PHP code looks fine to me and should wrap div.card. Do you by chance have a javascript library that tinkers with the .card class?

Can you change the .card and .card__content classes and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @cptnk - Yup still the same result. I've even tried to edit the HTML via Chrome inspect menu and wrap the `<a>` around `.card`, but it just spits the anchor and div as separate elements (`.card` is not a child of `a`). Wrapping divs in anchor tags is valid in HTML5 so unsure why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap div structure in  tag then its added multiple blank  tags because this is not the block tag, if you want to achieve like this then you need to with jQuery wrap().
Here i add updated code of your, will you please try this.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="card" id="linkBox_<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <div class="card__content">
                <h3 class="title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 50, '...');?></h3>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 30, '...' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
       <?php
              $tc1 = '#linkBox_' . $i;
        ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                t_ID = '<?php echo $tc1 ?>';
        $(t_ID).wrap( '<a class="whole_box_link" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"></a>' );
    });</script>
<?php $i++;
 endwhile; 
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code for removing blank p tag CODE:

```
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/"; 
preg_replace($pattern,'',get_the_content());
```

Comment: That is not what the question is about.